# Uploading a large file to Google Storage directly from App engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine-python

I'm trying to build a system where a user selects a large dataset from their dropbox, and this data is downloaded to a google cloud storage bucket.

The problem is that my backend code runs on AppEngine, and therefore I cannot download the large file to disk for uploading to the bucket.

Is there a way to programmatically tell Cloud storage to retrieve data from a URL?

Or is there another way to download this data on an AppEngine instance, and upload it from there?

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly tell GCS to please download one file from the Internet and save it in a bucket.

On the other hand, moving a large collection of objects is the business of Google's Storage Transfer service. It may suit your needs, depending on what you mean by "a large dataset." https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/overview